# What is a honest Markov process?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I read this term in: http://www.proba.jussieu.fr/pageperso/amaury/index_fichiers/Guanajuato.pdf

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this. Is there a formal definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Markov process $(X_t)_{t\geqslant0}$ with values in $[0,+\infty]$ is honest if $\mathrm P_x(X(t)=+\infty)=0$ for every time $t$ and every starting point $x$.